# Run code after the app has terminated... Possible? (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background

I was just wondering if it's possible to run some code after and while an app is terminated. I want to have data on a remote database checked on every few seconds by the app, and if anything changes, the user should be notified (using local notifications, I guess?). While the app is running I can easily do this, using the interval method of NSTimer, but I was wondering what the alternative would be if the app was terminated. If I Google around, it almost seems as if there's literally NO WAY of doing this, but that seems kinda strange and unlikely to me, since there's a boatload of apps out there (any social networking app, for example) that can notify you when something happens/changes in your account, even when the app is completely closed. I'm pretty sure those apps have to run some code eventually if they want to notify me on my device, right? How do they do it?

Comment: this may help you:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: You should use push notifications from a server.  Polling is very inefficient in terms of battery and network data.

Comment: @janusfidel This documentation only covers background execution (when the app is still open, but in the background, like after pressing the Home button on your device). I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm asking about. Does this also refer to execution after an app was TERMINATED (completely shut down, after double-pressing the Home-button and swiping the app's screenshot up)?

Comment: @FreddyBenson yes, see topic 'Implementing Long-Running Tasks'

Comment: @Paulw11 Aren't Push Notifications supposed to be triggered by someone? That's not what I'm looking for, I want notifications to be triggered when some events occur (for example: user "Liked" an image or user started following another user). Can this be done using Push notifications?

Comment: Push notifications are triggered by whatever code you write. On your server you can write code than runs when someone likes something and sends a push notification

Comment: @Paulw11 Where can you do this? I was told you can only use Push notifications from a cloud server like CloudKit or Parse, in which you can only send a Push notification by manually triggering it yourself. Where can you write code to trigger a Push notification? Not in Xcode, right?

Comment: @janusfidel Under the tab "Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background", underneath the last category of examples, the first line reads: "In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user". Googled it to confirm my assumption and yes: by 'force quitting' Apple means double-pressing the Home-button and swiping up your app screenshot. In other words, doesn't this line implicitly state that you CAN'T run any code after the app is terminated? It's so confusing how everyone has a different definition of "running in the background".

Comment: Asking "how can I run code after my app is terminated?" is much the same as asking "how can I keep breathing once I am dead?"  PushKit will relaunch VoIP apps from a terminated state when a PushKit remote notification is received and location services will relaunch a terminated app in some instances but generally if the user terminates an app iOS assumes the user wanted it dead and won't relaunch it.

Comment: You will need code running on a server somewhere. CloudCode in Parse is one way to do it; You can use an `afterSave` block to send the pushes when a record is updated. In theory you could have the iOS app initiate the appropriate push when it updated the database, but once you get to large scale it is better to have the server do it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Parse is being shut down soon, so there's no point in starting to work with that now. And it seems like almost every Push-supporting cloud server obligates you to use their own database to store records (like CloudKit and Firebase for example). Isn't there anything out there I can use to observe changes in my MySQL database, where I keep all my data?

Comment: You can run parse on your own server, but no I am not aware of any service that can monitor an existing MySQL instance and send pushes. First, you would need to write code anyway because even if there was a service that detected a change it needs some code to interpret that change and know where to send the push. Second polling is stupid when you can write code in your web services layer that updates the underlying database to send the required pushes.  Please tell me you haven't just got a raw MySQL connection between an app and a database server?

Comment: @Paulw11 You mean a direct connection between the client and the database?! Nah, I'm pretty sure that's not even possible. I've been using PHP-written web services to let the client interact with the database, but I've never gotten around to letting the web services observe any changes in the database. Honestly, I've only been using it for storing, retrieving and updating data in my MySQL databases. If that's possible (which I'm hoping it is), I would have to check out how to let the web services keep track of changes in my database. But I assume you wouldn't have any experience with this?

Comment: The web service is the thing that is *making the change*. It doesn't need to keep track of anything. When there is an update to a "like", for example at the same time it updates the database the code can send push notifications.

Comment: @Paulw11 Right... but I was actually referring to the hypothetical scenario in which the web service is NOT the thing that is making the change (think along the lines of me updating/adding data in MySQL manually). Never mind, though, I'll figure it out. I'll start by adding the code that notifies the client some data in the database has changed.

Comment: Right, well, don't do that; always use the services layer.  Or if you do, you need to manually run some code to send the notifications.  You are overthinking this.  Monitoring the database is categorically the *wrong way to go about this*.  Architect your application correctly, build the business logic in the right place (the PHP service) and don't bypass it.

Answer (score 2):

So after figuring out what everyone's own definition of "running in the background" and "terminating an app" is, I'm guessing the most adequate and yet so simple answer to this much asked question is: NO, YOU CANNOT! The only way to trigger some code which is written on your client-side (in Xcode in my case), is to have the client notified that some events have occurred on a remote server, which in iOS would have to happen by sending notifications to APNS, to which the client would have to 'respond' to the notification in an appropriate way. However, what I was asking about, whether or not you could just write some code in Xcode which would keep running even after the app has been terminated by the user (double-pressed Home button to kill your app by swiping up the screenshot): NO! There is NO WAY of doing this without a remote server getting involved in the process.